# How to push the value in object in proper format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my code to get the languages with Language id and language text

```
for (var p in $scope.bulk.Langugaes) {
    $scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue.push($scope.bulk.Langugaes[p].Value, $scope.bulk.Langugaes[p].Text);
}
```

but for above code the value in lsLanguagewithTextndValue

```
0:"1"
1:"Marathi"
2:"2"
3:"English"
4:"4"
5:"Hindi"
6:"3"
7:"French"
```

But I want output like this

```
1:Marathi
2:English
3.Hindi
4.French
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on  the structure of
$scope.bulk.Langugaes and $scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue.push({ $scope.bulk.Langugaes[p].Value: $scope.bulk.Langugaes[p].Text });
```

Multiple arguments in .push just pushes each argument in to the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a pair `key - value` do it like this:

```
obj[key] = value;
```

In your case it should be something like this:

```
for (var p in $scope.bulk.Langugaes) {
    $scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue[$scope.bulk.Langugaes[p].Value] = $scope.bulk.Langugaes[p].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use map [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This function make a new array with elements of another.

```
$scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue =
    $scope.bulk.Langugaes.map((langugaes) => {
         // langugaes its a element of $scope.bulk.Langugaes for example 
         // $scope.bulk.Langugaes[p]
         return {langugaes.Value: langugaes.Text}
    })
```

Result:

```
  {
    "1": "Marathi"
  },
  {
    "2": "English"
  },
  {
    "3": "Hindi"
  },
  {
    "4": "French"
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19747229)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const $scope = {
  bulk: {
    Languages: {
      ln1: { value: 1, text: 'Marathi' },
      ln2: { value: 2, text: 'English' },
      ln3: { value: 3, text: 'Hindi' },
      ln4: { value: 4, text: 'French' }
    }
  },
  lsLanguagewithTextndValue: []
}

// just to make it more readable
const langs = $scope.bulk.Languages;

for (let p in langs) {
  $scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue.push({[langs[p].value]: langs[p].text})
}

console.log($scope.lsLanguagewithTextndValue);
```